# How can .m3u8 and .ts streams or videos properly be saved, without any pixelated or corrupted frames? VLC or FFMPEG, or anything else

Tags: audio, video, vlc-media-player, streaming, media

I was wondering how to save contents of .m3u8, generally any that works, using VLC at "Open Network Stream".
I saw that these files often contain .ts files, that are named "playlist".

I've also tried to locally download the .m3u8, then edit the playlist .ts files to point to the server URL, so that I can load it in VLC and play it. Like that, I was able to choose the part I wanted to save.

Now, when it comes to saving it, there were some issues, basically the frames didn't look like they were supposed, compared to how the video plays in the website or on VLC, I guess, though I am not sure about that. This issue occurs when selecting "Converting", not sure if there are options that I can provide, so that the quality doesn't break.

If you would play one of these .m3u8 files on VLC Player, there are loading issues at the beginning. It seems like that some video related data has first to be gathered, because after that, no issues occured anymore. And I think the "Converting" option in VLC doesn't seem to be doing that, by default at least.

Therefore, the other method I tried, was to click on "Stream" in VLC, this allows me to "Stream" a content in VLC to a file. This seemed to have worked fine, however the quality wasn't great, especially when a lot of color appeared, you ended up seeing a lot of pixels.

And now I am wonder, how can you save one of these things properly?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i https://example.com/stream.m3u8 -codec copy output.mkv`?

Comment: Don't turn on transcoding. Probably you turned it on and it reencoded the stream instead of dumping the original encoded data to a file.

Comment: @TBR I assume you're talking about VLC. For which one? Converting or Stream?